# Get the Q function value for a Probability Density Function with an absolute value

Tags: probability-distributions, error-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $ \mu  $ and variance $ \sigma ^ 2 $. Then how do we express the probability $P(|X| \ge t)$ in terms of the Q function (error function) where $t\geq 0$ is a constant.

I know that we can get this as a folded normal variable and show that $$P(|X| \ge t) = Q \left({t-\mu \over \sigma}\right) + Q \left({t+\mu \over \sigma}\right)$$

Could someone explain how to obtain this result?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I just edited your question: am I correct in guessing that $X$ is distributed as a Gaussian?

Comment: @Kore-N, Yes, It is Gaussian